# How to reason about CVEs packaged in other open source software

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, patching

I am reasoning about how to form a policy on CVEs found in software components that do not come from the software itself, but comes in a built-in dependency of that software.

Take the example of a software component built on Java maintained by organization X. That would typically come packed with a lot of 3rd party dependencies that may have CVEs.
Scanning that software component may then find a vulnerability CVE-Z in a dependency of the software component that comes from another another organization Y.

It will in many scenarios require a lot of work to understand if this CVE-Z is a problem in that software component. And there will often be a lot of "embedded CVEs".
I myself assume that most actively maintained servers will update if they suffer from high rated CVEs in embedded libraries, but I am not willing to trust that 100%
Has anyone some good reasoning on how to think about this and work with it?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to create a policy around things that you don't control. Your policies should be around things that you control, which are the direct dependencies of your systems.

One aspect of your policy should be due diligence before bringing in a new dependency. Do not limit yourself to current CVEs, but the current state of open issues and how the maintainers of the dependency respond to open issues. Looking at the dependency's governance policies - how many people use the dependency, who the contributors to the dependency are and how often contributions happen, how the development team manages bug reports, release frequency, how they manage their dependencies, how reports of potential security vulnerabilities are accepted and triaged - can be used to make an informed decision about the risks of bringing in one dependency over another or choosing to build your own.

Depending on your environment, you may even choose to use your tools to perform static analysis and vulnerability scans on any open-source dependencies. Not only can you use this to make your decision on using a dependency, but you can provide feedback, if not contributions, to the dependency to resolve issues. Depending on how you license your tools (for example, some commercial tools are based on the number of scanned lines of code).

The next aspect of your policy should be monitoring of your dependencies using software composition analysis tools. You're correct that it takes a lot of work to understand if a given CVE would impact you, but even if it does, the best you can do is implement mitigations, unless you have the time and knowledge to contribute to your entire dependency tree. Reviewing the findings and regularly patching your direct dependencies is the first line of defense. I'd keep in mind that SCA tools are only reporting vulnerabilities that are in their database - any dependency, direct or transitive, may have defects or vulnerabilities that are unreported and wouldn't show up in any scan or report.

In the longer-term, some SCA tools give some health metrics on dependencies. If a dependency is no longer being actively maintained, plan to replace it with one that is. Alternatively, go through the same review that you did when choosing the dependency in the first place and decide if you should continue to maintain your direct dependency or switch to an alternative (including rolling your own solution).

Focus your policy on managing what you can control (your direct dependency) and awareness of the things you can't control (your transitive dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not as simple to consider that "they will surely update their dependency if they are affected". That's what *should* happen, but sadly it's not always the case.

At the same time, there are indeed many CVEs which would not be applicable to a specific usage.

Plus there could be as well false positives in that the tool may be detecting component Y as vulnerable to CVE-Z, while it is actually a version with a backported fix.

I would ask the vendor X "What is their policy on keeping tabs on the vulnerabilities of the components they use in their software?". A minimally security conscious company should have "something", even if it's quite basic, whereas one which isn't would probably not even know what you are asking about (not just the salesman, nobody in the company).

A company that kept track of this could easily provide (e.g. in a couple of days) a "[Software Bill of Materials](https://www.cisa.gov/sbom)" of the components they use, the CVE they have and their status regarding their product X, because they already have that, and such assessment was already done internally. The second would have to analyze all of them.

Of course, evaluate critically their responses, timing, void language which adds nothing, depth and matching with what you observe. It is simple for a company to say "We always ship the latest version of the components, and release a maintenance release whenever there is a new vulnerability on any of them." But if they are embedding a 5-year-old versions of a component with much newer releases, that wouldn't seem to be really what they do.

In fact, I would find suspicious to see such an old library on a recent release, since the easiest way to ensure you are not vulnerable (and shut up the automated scanners) is generally to simply update the component. It suggests they aren't really keeping them up-to-date.

CISA has been doing a lot of work on this line, and on the European side, NIS 2 also addresses the importance of vulnerabilities in the supply chain. So while you might be seen as "picky", you should be able to easily justify you are just following the best practices, are by far not the only one doing this and how surprising their company hadn't heard of it.

If you are a signing a contract with the company selling the software, that's the best place a few paragraphs about their obligations regarding the security of their software and your right to request information on certain timelines. If you don't have that leverage, it may be harder.

Of course, taking into account these security aspects mean that you may have to reject on this bases a number of vendors, potentially ending up with a more expensive one (despite the fact that "more expensive" doesn't mean "more security conscious" which is what we are really after). You should value yourself the risk on each case.

These are generic considerations, applicable regardless of the software being open source or not.

If the software you are getting is open source there are really not that many differences. Even if you had the option to download it for free, you may nevertheless want to get a commercial subscription for that, get a maintenance contract with the developers and/or a third party that could provide you with the assurance that any security issues will be promptly addressed. Just like you would have to do with normal commercial software.